# Given a list of points on a rectilinear path, identify the corners

Tags: geometry, logic, algorithms

> You are provided list of co-ordinates in form of pair as shown below:
>
> $$li=[(576, 64), (576, 192), (448, 192), (320, 192), (320, 320), (192, 320), (192, 448), (192, 576), (320, 576), (448, 576), (576, 576), (704, 576), (832, 576), (960, 576)]$$
>
> **After modifying it according to goal.**
>
> Goal is to first plot all points in co-ordinate plane then join them now carefully we need to find out all corner points.
>
> $$li=[(576, 64), (576, 192),(320, 192), (320, 320), (192, 320), (192, 576), (960, 576)]$$

Please refer the image I need the points which are encircled by a blue rectangle, where as red circled points are points that are provided in the problem.

[image]

I tried brute force approach it worked but yes please I need something better than that.

Comment: This seems like a question for the programming-oriented [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), or possibly even [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com). In any case, you should include your "brute force" approach, and explain what you find unsatisfactory about it, so that people don't duplicate your effort and also have a baseline against which to judge what might count as "something better".

Comment: Let $p_i = (x_i,y_i), i = 1,\ldots,n$ be the points. Let $q_i = (u_i,v_i) = p_{i+1} - p_i$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n-1$. If $q_i$ and $q_{i+1}$ is not parallel ( $u_i v_{i+1} - v_i u_{i+1} \ne 0$), then $p_{i+1}$ is a corner.

Comment: @solver: Off the top of my head, I'd compare each point $p_i$ (starting with the third) to its "second predecessor", $p_{i-2}$. If the $x$-coordinates differ *and* the $y$-coordinates differ, then the "first predecessor", $p_{i-1}$, is a corner. This test ignores the first and last points, but they're already "corners" by declaration.

Comment: @Blue yes next time I will, thnx to Achille hui also I was looping over every point so time complexity got n^2

Comment: @Blue thnx a lot ur method just take O(n) and is very efficient, I realized it today earlier I didn't noticed the hidden beauty in ur algo :)

Comment: I can't figure out what you call brute force, please explain your method (it could turn out that it is already optimal).

Comment: @Yyes dear as I was choosing a point then running a loop for further points so actually .... If u get lot of points on straight line and loop in manner as described then obviously for large test cases u exhaust time limit :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a comment (with some adjustments) to an answer, as OP is satisfied with its validity ...

---

For each index $i$ (starting with the second, and ending with the next-to-last), compare $p_{i-1}$ to $p_{i+1}$: if (and only if) their $x$-coordinates differ *and* their $y$-coordinates differ, then (and only then) $p_i$ is a corner.

This algorithm ignores the first and last points, but those are already "corners" by declaration.

As OP has noted, the algorithm has complexity $O(n)$, as it simply steps through the list once.